# Building Oauth2 for C on Windows

Tags: c, windows, oauth-2.0

I'm attempting to add Oauth2 to an existing program. The program uses C, and is compiled on a Windows machine using Visual Studio 2010. I believe I need the Iddawc library, recommended by Okta, but they do not provide pre-built libraries, and the code is designed to be built on various flavors of Linux.
I tried downloading Make for Windows, but despite there being a Makefile, when I run it, I get this message:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I've also attempted to include the library files in the existing project (an ugly, temporary solution at best), but this sends me down a seemingly unending chain of other libraries that are required and does not appear to be a feasible option.

Is there a (hopefully simple) way to get this library to build on Windows?

Answer (score 0):

For iddawc, you could try building with MinGW-w64. The easiest way to do that is by installing [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org).

An alternative that might work for you is [liboauth2](https://github.com/zmartzone/liboauth2). At a glance, there's some Windows code in their codebase.